# Set environment in integration tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, testing, .net-core

I want to set environment in my integration tests using `WebApplicationFactory`. by defualt, env is set to `Development`. Code of my web application factory looks like this:

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup>
    where TStartup : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseSolutionRelativeContentRoot(AppContext.BaseDirectory);

        base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);
    }

    protected override IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder()
    {
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseStartup<TStartup>()
            .UseEnvironment("test"); // i want to launch `test` environment while im
                                     // testing my app
    }
}
```

When i start to debug `Startup` class (while i run tests) i still getting `Development` environment:

```
public Startup(IHostEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
        // env.EnvironmentName is set to 'Development' while i set it to 'test'
        // in my WebApplicationFactory
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

How to set environment in `WebApplicationFactory` properly? Or maybe how to change strategy for tests only when in startup i depends on `appsettings` files?

Comment: This discussion may be helpful to you： https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/12303

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I had the same issue and following worked out for me:

```
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
     builder.UseEnvironment("Test");
}
```

Comment: Add `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;` before using this method.

Answer (score 11):

As an alternative, if you aren't using a custom `WebApplicationFactory`, you can specify the environment using the `WithWebHostBuilder` extension method:

```cs
var application = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>()
    .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
    {
        builder.UseEnvironment("Test");
    });
```

Tested in .Net 6.0

Answer (score 11):

### Full source code using .NET 6 MVC project:

https://github.com/akhanalcs/mvc-integration-test

---

**Step 1:**
Create a class named `CustomWebApplicationFactory` in your test project.

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TProgram>
    : WebApplicationFactory<TProgram> where TProgram : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        // Works for: Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") in Program.cs
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "test");
        
        // OR

        // Works for: builder.Environment.EnvironmentName in Program.cs
        builder.UseEnvironment("test"); 
    }
}
```

**Step 2:**
Create `SomeServiceTests.cs` file and use it from there. (I'm using MSTest here)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;

namespace SomeProject.IntegrationTests.SomeServiceTests;

[TestClass]
public class SomeServiceTests
{
    private static WebApplicationFactory<Program> _factory;

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void ClassInit(TestContext testContext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(testContext.TestName);
        _factory = new CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>();
    }

    [ClassCleanup]
    public static void ClassCleanup()
    {
        _factory.Dispose();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Some_Test_Method_Here_Async()
    {
        // ARRANGE
        var client = _factory.CreateClient();

        // If I wanted to resolve some service:
        //using var scope = _factory.Services.CreateScope();
        //var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
        //var db = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

        // ACT

        // ASSERT
    }
}
```

**Step 3:**
I use the environment variable in my `Program.cs` like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? builder.Environment.EnvironmentName;

builder.Configuration
       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
       .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

// Rest of the code here
```

Answer (score 2):

Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().ConfigureWebHost(e => e.UseEnvironment("Development"))

I inferred the solution from these URLs :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 1):

In your CustomApplicationFactory you should override CreateWebHostBuilder method with following code:

```
protected override IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder()
{
    return base.CreateWebHostBuilder().UseEnvironment("test");
}
```

Comment: ConfigureWebHost is called during the CreateWebHostBuilder method, therefore the "Test" environment won't be changed until after the Config is run, which in many cases is too late.